# Python NameError: name 'Print' is not defined

Tags: python

I am running a print command on the interpreter that prints this error:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> Print ("Hello World")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    Print ("Hello World")
NameError: name 'Print' is not defined
>>> Print ('Hello World')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Print ('Hello World')
NameError: name 'Print' is not defined
>>> Print("Hello World")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    Print("Hello World")
NameError: name 'Print' is not defined
```

How can `Print` not be defined?

Answer (score 18):

Function and keyword names are case-sensitive in Python. Looks like you typed `Print` where you meant `print`.

Answer (score 8):

Python is case sensitive.

`print('Hello World')`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your "Print" has got the wrong casing. print should be in lowercase

Answer (score 3):

It's not `Print` it's `print`. Lowercase p.

Answer (score 1):

Python distinguishes uppercase and lowercase two different characters during execution. The reason for this is python doesn't want us to restrict the usages of identifiers and symbols to be used.

how to print hello world in python?

print('Hello World')

Answer (score 0):

Use "print" instead of "Print".

Answer (score 0):

`Print` is nothing in python.

You mean `print`.

I think you need to remove the space between `print` and `("Hello World")`

You mean `print("Hello World")`

Final code: `print("Hello World")`

Comment: The space is irrelevant here. (It is better coding style to remove it, but it doesn't affect the program's function in any way.) And the rest of the answer just duplicates what at least 5 people already said.

Answer (score 0):

Change Print to print(lower case p)

Answer (score 0):

For printing Words on python should try this

```
print ("Your Words")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `print(" ")`  with lower case `p` in `print` function

Python is a case sensitive language, so `print` and `Print` is 2 different function

Answer (score 0):

As everybody highlighted Python is case sensitive and it should be `print` not `Print`, but I'm not going to repeat it. If you are new to python you can use `Linting` to highlight syntactical and stylistic problems in your Python source code.

Refer to this VS Code plugin for more details about linting: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Answer (score -1):

please hover over run button and run as python file

Comment: what run button? In what application? Where in that application?

Comment: In vscode whenever you run the program just run the code as run as python file